# cmyk color specification in SVG 1.2

Tags: image, svg, rgb, cmyk

According to the SVG 1.2 standard, support is now offered for icc-color specfication (according to this link: [W3.org spec for SVG 1.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGColor12/#icc-colors)

I tried it with the following... this is the entire file, two circles, both should be green

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <parent xmlns="http://example.org"
            xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
       <svg:svg width="400" height="200" version="1.2">
          <svg:ellipse cx="100" cy="100" rx="100" ry="100" 
            fill="rgb(0,255,0)" />
          <svg:ellipse cx="300" cy="100" rx="100" ry="100" 
            fill="rgb(0,255,0) device-cmyk(0.11, 0.48, 0.83, 0.00)" />
       </svg:svg>
    </parent>
```

However, when I try to view it with IE9 or Chrome, the second circle is black. The only thing that renders both circles as green is GIMP 2 (of what I've tried so far).

The RGB is supposed to be the fallback color... does adding the CMYK part just mess it up so badly for a browser that it's unusable? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the top of the document, you'll see SVG 1.2 is a working draft from 2009. It was never completed and no browser ever implemented it.